# Echoing only a div with php

Tags: php, foreach, echo

I'm attempting to make a script that only echos the div that encolose the image on google.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/";
$page = file($url);

foreach($page as $theArray) {
echo $theArray;
}
```

The problem is this echos the whole page.
I want to echo only the part between the `<div id="lga">` and the next closest `</div>`
Note: I have tried using if's but it wasn't working so I deleted them

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in DOM methods:

```
<?php

$page = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");

$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($page);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
$lga = $domx->query("//*[@id='lga']")->item(0);

$domd2 = new DOMDocument();
$domd2->appendChild($domd2->importNode($lga, true));

echo $domd2->saveHTML();
```

Comment: +1, but note that this may not be friendly if the text isn't properly parse-able

Comment: PHP's DOM library is pretty powerful when it comes to handling invalid html, I only met a few problematic pages so far, but they all were FUBAR.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this you need to parse the DOM and then get the ID you are looking for.  Check out a parsing library like this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

After feeding your html document into the parser you could call something like:

```
$html = str_get_html($page); 
$element = $html->find('div[id=lga]'); 
echo $element->plaintext;
```

That, I think, would be your quickest and easiest solution.

Comment: maerlyn had error checking so I gave it to him, thanks though.